# How do I install compiled script from setup.py in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, setuptools, distutils

Consider the following `setup.py` file (for the example the only other source file (`false.c`) is generated right here):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
from distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler
from subprocess import check_call

with open('false.c', 'w') as F:
    F.write('int main(int argc, char **argv){ return 1; }\n')

compiler = new_compiler().compiler

check_call(compiler + ['-O3', 'false.c', '-o', 'false'])

setup(
    name='false',
    scripts=['false'],
)
```

. This file works fine when using python-2* (when using `pip install -e .` while in a directory with this `setup.py` file) installing compiled `false` executable to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin`. But if I use virtual environment with python-3* it fails with the following error: ([full error log](http://bpaste.net/show/151296/))

```
<...>
  File "/home/zyx/.virtenvs/python3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 27, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "/home/zyx/.virtenvs/python3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 105, in install_for_development
    self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
  File "/home/zyx/.virtenvs/python3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in process_distribution
    self.install_egg_scripts(dist)
  File "/home/zyx/.virtenvs/python3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 138, in install_egg_scripts
    script_text = f.read()
  File "/home/zyx/.virtenvs/python3.2/lib64/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 208: invalid start byte
<...>
```

Comment: The closes thing to the solution is using `data_files=[('bin', ['false'])]`. But this is not going to work with `pip install -e`, only `pip install` without `-e`.

Comment: Does it work if you use pure distutils instead of setuptools?  This may be a Python 3 conversion bug, where the file is opened in text mode but should have used binary mode, in case it’s not a script.